# Using a Small Signal Relay in Automotive Application

Tags: relay, automotive

I want to implement a 12V relay (https://www.mouser.com/ProductDetail/Panasonic-Industrial-Devices/TX2SA-12V?qs=HLLy2pIPwuuBcCVwky7PWw%3D%3D)
in an automotive application.

I will be using the car's 12V battery power to control the relay coil. The signal I am switching is battery 12V going into a high impedance input, so very little current will flow through the contacts, necessitating the use of a small signal relay.

Using a transistor is not possible as there would be no voltage drop between gate and source since this is not a low/high side switch.

I am concerned because I cannot find a small signal relay rated for automotive use, particularly vibration. I am also concerned how the relay coil will respond to the noisy battery power, and whether I will experience unexpected switching under conditions such as load dump or starting.

Is this a valid concern, and if so, what measures should I take to prevent issues?

Comment: Have you thought about using an automotive rated relay?

Comment: I have updated the post to include why I am not using an automotive relay

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was incorrect in one of of my assumptions in this question.

The input I am going into is an ignition input on an ECU. These are generally pulled down internally, which means you can use a MOSFET to switch the signal, since the drain will be at 12V and the source will be at ground.

I did end up using the small signal relay, and one of the surface-mount legs of the relay eventually broke due to vibration. My solution was to epoxy the body of the relay to the board, but in the future I would use a through hole relay.